# Customer account is temporarily disabled in magento

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2

I am trying to call customer login api.

```
{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

with body

```
{
    "username" : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    "password" : "fsfsdf"
}
```

I am  getting an  error

**"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."**

But i am able to login through **magento website**.This error is getting only for particular email ids.Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an open issue in mganeto 2.

[Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4432)

Magento2  keeps track of failed attempts to get a token with an email and the wrong password (in the `oauth_token_request_log` table). If the failures_count column reaches the max allowed value (which is 6 by default). then authentication fails.

A temporary solution that i have done, is running  cron job that does this cleanup on the database.

```
DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;
```

The above SQL will runs in every 1 minute.

Comment: You mean need to create a Cron for oauth_token_request_log clean
can you enplane about that

Comment: Is this workaround completely working? For me I have still the same error message.

Comment: @Muhsin, I have cleared the table `oauth_token_request_log` but still having the same issue, it does not help in my case.

Comment: +1 This was the solution for my problem. It was pretty hard to find this solution actually. I am glad I found it.